# ChromeDriver org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the error I get. I have been changing the version of ChromeDriver and Chrome several times and nothing helped. Can someone please find a way to resolve this? junit 4.12 selenium version 3.141.59
Regards to all

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe"
    Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.12 (220b19a666554bdcac56dff9ffd44c300842c933-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#83}) on port 45366
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
    kwi 22, 2020 7:32:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Panel.GeneralForm.selectClose(GeneralForm.java:63)
        at FormTest.test_for_contact_page(FormTest.java:12)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


    Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: would be usefull if you provide code as well

Comment: Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v823vnavnj524uh/bmTest.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing null pointer issue due to misssing initialization of your webdriver in each page object class, PageFactory is inbuilt page object model concept in Selenium. Along with annotation its also allowing static init method for initializing web elements.

You can use below init method in each page object model :

```
   public className(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
   }
```